# How to transform a formula into clausal form?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

Transform the following formula to clausal form:

$∀x∀y(∃zp(z)∧∃u(q(x, u)→∃vq(y, v)))$

Attempt:

Recall the

**Definition:** A closed formula is in clausal form if and only if it's prefix are only universal quantifiers.

Thus $∀x∀y(∃zp(z)∧∃u(q(x, u)→∃vq(y, v)))\iff ∀x∀y\ (\lnot(\forall zp(z)\lor \forall u(q(x, u)\to∃vq(y, v)))\iff ? $

I am stuck here, I don't know how to take out the quantifiers $\forall z$ and $\forall u$ without the $\lnot$ ?

Could someone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to transform a first-order formula into a clause form, follow the rules listed [here](http://imada.sdu.dk/~felhar07/dm509e13/notes/convert_clausal.pdf) (see also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form#Converting_from_first-order_logic)).

According to that, your formula is transformed as follows ($f,g,h$ are new binary function symbols introduced by [Skolemization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form)):

\begin{align}
\forall x \forall y \big(\exists z \, p(z) \land \exists u (q(x, u) \to \exists v \, q(y, v)) \big) 
&\equiv \forall x \forall y \big(\exists z \, p(z) \land \exists u (\lnot q(x, u) \lor \exists v \, q(y, v)) \big) \\
&\equiv \forall x \forall y \exists z \exists u \exists v \big(p(z) \land (\lnot q(x, u) \lor q(y, v)) \big) \\
&\equiv \forall x \forall y \big(p(f(x,y)) \land (\lnot q(x, g(x,y)) \lor q(y, h(x,y))) \big)
\end{align}

Comment: :) got it, thank you.

Comment: I am working in a similar exercise and I have 1 question, how to interpret this $\lnot\exists yp(y)$? 1. $\forall yp(y)$ or 2.$\forall y\lnot p(y)$?

Comment: @Michelle - $\lnot \exists yp(y)$ is equivalent to $\forall y \lnot p(y)$. Indeed, $\lnot \exists yp(y)$ means that there is no one with the property $p$, i.e. everyone does not have the property $p$.

Comment: oh ok, one step of Skolemization says that the formula must be written in CNF, but if there's only $\lor 's$ or only $\land 's$ is still in CNF right?

Comment: Yes, they are CNF.

Comment: Can I repeat steps in the Skolemization?, i.e. at first I changed this $\forall x\exists x$ by this $\forall x\exists y$. But due application of negations I returned to something like this $\forall x\exists x$. Can I change again the name of the variables?

Comment: @Michelle - Could you be more explicit?

Comment: Yes, I have this formula $\forall x A(x)\leftrightarrow\lnot\exists x\lnot A(x)$. So I had to change the $x$ variable by $y$ variable: $\forall x A(x)\leftrightarrow\lnot\exists y\lnot A(y)$. I continue with the Skolemization process and then I got $\exists x\lnot A(x)\lor\forall y A(y))\land \exists yA(y)\lor\forall xA(x))$ and as you can see there are variables that share quantifiers. So must they be changed again according to Skolemization rules?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75233/discussion-between-taroccoesbrocco-and-michelle).